# javascript functionalize if statement

Tags: javascript

I have a general function for summarizing data (counting, summing, average, etc) I would like to add criteria to it, something like this.

```
function summarize(data, criteria, criteriaCol, criteriaValue)
  for(i=0;i<data.length){
      if(data[i][criteriaCol] criteria criteriaValue){
        //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

in this example I would like criteria to be an operator

Comment: Do you mean you would input for `criteria` something like `"=="`,`"!="`, `">"` and would like the if conditon comparison to act as if those were actual operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the `summarize` function accept a function as the `criteria` argument:

```
function summarize(data, criteriaCol, criteriaValue, criteria)
{
  for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      if(criteria(data[i][criteriaCol], criteriaValue)){
           //Do something.
        }
    }
}
```

Lets say you would like to perform an operation on the elements whos forth column are smaller than a `criteriaValue` of five. Then you would do it like this:

```
function smallerThan(data, value) {
    return data < value;
}

summarize(data, 4, 5, smallerThan);
```

Alternatively, you can declare the function inline:

```
summarize(data, 4, 5, function(data, value) {
    return data < value;
});
```

You can make a function per operator, or even make more complex functions that does more than a simple comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you asked, since your question is too broad, but wouldn't it be the case to make a switch statement to each criteria?

```js
function check (data, criteria, val){
    switch (criteria){
  case "<":
   return data < val;
  case ">":
   return data > val;
  case "<=":
   return data <= val;
  case ">=":
   return data >= val;
  case "==":
  default:
   return data === val;
 }
}

function summarize(data, criteria, criteriaCol, criteriaValue)
  for(i=0;i<data.length){
      if(check(data[i][criteriaCol], criteria, criteriaValue) ){
        //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```